# Where can I find Mahabharata stories about Krishna?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna

Stories about his training, the wrestling, the mental training, how he went and killed his maternal uncle Kamsa, the Kurkurestra war, etc.

Comment: Harivansh Purana

Comment: Story of krishna from childhood to Student days is given Srimad Bhavgavatha dashama skanda .. CANTO 10. The Adulthood stories are given in Mahabharatha itself..

Comment: @Prasanna Since you know the source, please consider adding that as answer.

Comment: @Prasanna Since you know the source, please consider adding that as answer.

Answer (score 6):

Story of Krishna from childhood to Student days is given Srimad Bhavgavatha dashama skanda CANTO 10.
http://srimadbhagavatam.org/canto10/c10-1-contents.html

The Adulthood stories are given in Mahabharatha itself. But this spread across all 18 parvas.